# How did Rio know so quickly who robbed the store?

Tags: plot-explanation, good-girls

In the Netflix series *[Good Girls](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6474378/)*, three average women without any criminal past decide to rob a grocery store to get (to their best estimates) about 30.000$ that they desperately need.

After the heist, to their surprise, they find that they've got a bit more that they wanted:

> over 500.000 in dirty money laundered by the local gang. Rio, the money owner, quickly finds them and demands the money back.

Question is, how they have been found so quickly? Even police doesn't suspect them: The robbery went smoothly, if you don't count the manager, who recognized a tattoo on one of the robbers, but he doesn't seem to have any criminal connections (he even later on tries to sell robbers to FBI).

Comment: From my reading there *is no explanation* it's a "deus ex plot machina" issue. In other words, he finds out because the plot says he does.